# How to search internet

Tags: help

I've just downloaded Tor and can't find a search bar for browsing the internet. Keep looking and can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you download [Tor-Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) or [tor package](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) from a repository?

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the search bar right beside the address bar. I provided you with a screenshot. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to reach it.

[image: Search bar]

By default Tor Browser uses [Disconnect.me](https://disconnect.me/) as a search provider. If you click on the down arrow you can also choose another one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user service like Grams: http://grams7enufi7jmdl.onion/ to browse the deep web, or know the address of the site