# I cant seem to find a link directory

Tags: help

I am brand new and I cant find a directory to any websites except http://f6xtnh7l6ddsfzgy.onion/ ...helppp!

I cant seem to find any url because i simply dont know what to do or where to look or search

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following previous questions:

- [How do I find onion sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-do-i-find-onion-sites)
- [Where I can find, export or download the biggest list of all .onion addresses?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/where-i-can-find-export-or-download-the-biggest-list-of-all-onion-addresses)
- [How to search internet](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-search-internet)

If you have trouble connecting to any of the hidden services (i.e. `.onion` sites) that these previous answers mention, then it's likely that the sites are down, as described here: [Most .onion sites I am trying to access are unavailable: Why and how can I solve this?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/most-onion-sites-i-am-trying-to-access-are-unavailable-why-and-how-can-i-solve)